# How do I make a MVC project appear properly in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

How do I make a MVC project appear properly in Visual Studio?  I understand the logic of this sort of structure.  I have seen some blogs and explanations and even code segments explaining how a program can use MVC.  But I want to know what is a good way to represent a Model-View-Controller program in the Visual Studio.

For example, in an ASP.NET program, the asp.net file is associated with a C# file.  THey have the same name and, in the Solution Explorer window of the Visual Studio development environment, they are shown linked together where one is a tree branch of the other.  Should the same sort of thing be done for a MVC solution?  I can remember a few years ago, I worked on a MVVM project, and a developer who first put the solution file together actually had view and the view-model files arranged like this. In order to make this happen, he had to download some sort of patch that allowed him to edit the .sln (solution) file.

Is that the way to go for a Model-View-Controller program?  Should each be its own workspace in the solution, or should the solution file be edited such that each Model-View-Controller coupling be handled as a tree structure file representation kind of like it is done for an ASP.NET solution?

Here is another question.  What is a good template to use in Visual Studio to create an example of a Model-View-Controller program?  I tried this route but when I clicked to "get new templates", it did not work:

[image]
http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/Embedded/Capture_02_zps6vn4ri07.png

[image]
http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/Embedded/Capture_zpscdczk1b4.png

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots, it looks like you're using an old version of Visual Studio (either 2008 or 2010, there isn't enough showing to be sure, but I see the default .NET framework listed as 3.5 up there).

The latest versions of the ASP.NET MVC framework requires .NET 4.5. Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support this, so the solution is to upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio which includes support and project templates specifically for the latest versions of ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I do not want to use ASP.NET.  I only want to make a MVC project.  The View part of the MVC is an embedded system that, according to the party we are working with, requires Visual Studio 2008

Comment: Your question is tagged as ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET. You might want to change that if your goal is to avoid ASP.NET